# KeyError: Inserting data into database with API

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, python-requests

I've managed to enter data into this database before with other tables, however, when I'm trying to insert data into the Races table it gives me an error.

I had a look at the API I'm using and it would appear within the Races table there's a separate table called Circuit within the Races table, and it would seem that's where my problem is. I want to get data from both the Races and Circuit tables and add it into my database.

This is my code for this particular table:

```py
r = requests.get("https://ergast.com/api/f1/current.json") ## RACE SCHEDULE
r = r.json()
races = r["MRData"]["RaceTable"]["Races"]
#circuit =  r["MRData"]["RaceTable"]["Races"]["Circuit"]
for ra in races:
    rname = ra["raceName"]
    #for ci in circuit:
    tname = ra["circuitName"]
    rdate = ra["date"]
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Races(raceName, trackName, raceDate)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)''', (rname, tname, rdate))
database.commit()
print("done")
```

I'd expect the data to be added and then print done, but the error seems to be when it gets to the circuits section, it throws this error:

```
  File "E:\grace\SCHOOL\PROJECT\APIPractice.py", line 41, in <module>
    tname = ra["circuitName"]
KeyError: 'circuitName'
```

I have tried to change various variable names but each time it has given me an error (not necessarily this one). Is anyone able to help with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no key named `circuitName` in `r["MRData"]["RaceTable"]["Races"]` directly. 
The `circuitName` has one more key named `Circuit` in your json. You need to change the `tname`

```
    tname = ra['Circuit']["circuitName"]
```